Is it a good idea to unify the asset manager implementation across different parachains?
I'm currently learning about the XCM staff; it's always necessary to have an asset_id and XCM location mapping between HRMP-connected parachains when it comes to XCM transfers. I summarized the mapping implementation across different parachains, listed as follows:
# Moonbeam
* Darwinia -> pallet-asset-manager -> https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/moonbeam/blob/master/pallets/asset-manager/src/lib.rs
* Moonbeam -> pallet-asset-manager -> https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/moonbeam/blob/master/pallets/asset-manager/src/lib.rs
* Crust -> pallet-asset-manager -> https://github.com/crustio/crust/blob/polkadot-parachain/crust-collator/pallets/asset-manager/Cargo.toml

# orml
* Interlay -> orml-asset-registry -> https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library
* Pendulum -> orml-asset-registry -> https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library
* Centrifuge -> orml-asset-registry -> https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/open-runtime-module-library
* Zeitgeist -> orml-asset-registry -> https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/open-runtime-module-library

# Customized
* Hydration -> pallet-asset-registry -> https://github.com/galacticcouncil/hydration-node/blob/master/pallets/asset-registry/Cargo.toml   
* Acala -> module-asset-registry -> https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/Acala/blob/master/modules/asset-registry/Cargo.toml
* Astar -> pallet-xc-asset-config -> https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/master/pallets/xc-asset-config/Cargo.toml
* Bifrost -> bifrost-asset-registry -> https://github.com/bifrost-io/bifrost/blob/develop/pallets/asset-registry/Cargo.toml
* Manta -> pallet-asset-manager -> https://github.com/Manta-Network/Manta/blob/manta/pallets/asset-manager/src/lib.rs
* Ajuna -> pallet-asset-registry -> https://github.com/integritee-network/pallets.git 
* Composable -> pallet-assets-registry -> https://github.com/ComposableFi/composable/blob/main/code/parachain/frame/assets-registry/Cargo.toml 
* Phala -> assets-registry -> https://github.com/Phala-Network/khala-parachain/blob/main/pallets/assets-registry/Cargo.toml

# None
* Mythos -> None
* Unique -> None
* KILT -> None

I'm curious if it is possible to unify the implementation into one pallet in the polkadot-sdk or merge the mapping management into the pallet-asset or xcm modules. This way, for the applications powered by the xcm transfer, it would be much clearer and easier to integrate.

I find this discussion would be helpful. https://forum.polkadot.network/t/xcm-asset-registry/1168
